# How to add JSHint or ESLint or TSLint to Sonar qube?

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

Is there any option to add JSHint or ESLint or TSLint to [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/)? If it is there, could you please provide the step by step procedure.

Thanks,
Siva Ramanjaneyulu

Answer (score 1):

List of available plugins is [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Library).

You can use a [JavaScript Plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJS) to check JavaScript code.

You can also [create your own plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Developing+Plugins) which execute JSHint, ESLint or TSLint.

Comment: And this question is a good opportunity to remind why we don't simply provide a SonarQube JavaScript Plugin relying on existing JSHint and ESLint: http://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-javascript-plugin-why-compete-with-jslint-and-jshint/. For TSLint, this is another story because there isn't any SonarQube TypeScript plugin for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: https://github.com/groupe-sii/sonar-web-frontend-plugin

> Plugin for Sonarqube for the Web world with various technologies and languages (JavaScript, CSS, SASS, HTML, AngularJS...). This plugin consumes reports generated by tools that are heavily used by the Web community:
>
> Linters:
>   JSHint
>   CSS Lint
>   SCSS Lint
>   HTMLHint
>   Angular Hint
>   ESLint plugin for AngularJS
>
> Unit testing
>   Jasmine
>
> Code coverage:
>   Istanbul
>
> Code duplication
>   Simian
>   CPD
>
> Code complexity
>   Plato

Seems promising... :)

Comment: The tslint report consumer is broken. It does not understand tslint JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I have built a SonarPlugin for EsLint that supports AngularJs available on https://github.com/sleroy/SonarEsLintPlugin

I don't think SonarQube will allow it on the Marketplace therefore you will have to install it manually.