# How to lint Javascript code snippets in documentation

Tags: javascript, java, documentation, static-analysis

We have a whole lot of documentation about a software product in HTML. A lot of it is Javascript and Java snippets of code. We have many technical writers working on this but we worry that each has their own code style.

We'd like to make sure we present an error-free and uniform code style in our docs. However, doing code reviews on this volume of documentation is not practical. I wonder whether there's any way to run code review tools for both Javascript and Java *on these snippets* in the docs. I'm open to ideas.

## Edit:

Just to be clear, my problem is not finding a linter to use. The problem is that what I want to lint are not actual `.js` or `.java` files, but rather snippets of code within HTML files -e.g.:

***foo-tutorial.html***

```html
<html>
    <h2>How to do Foo</h2>
    <p>You can do Foo as follows:</p>
    <pre>
        function foo(foo1){
            console.log("Fooing with %s", foo1);
        }
    </pre>
</html>
```

I have a bunch of HTML files that look like the example above, and want to lint just the bits inside the `<pre>` element.

Comment: For javascript did you have a look at jslint? (of course javascript != java)

Comment: use eslint 
https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started
if want a common linting tool for both java and javascript, go with sonarQube
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31980013/how-to-add-jshint-or-eslint-or-tslint-to-sonar-qube

Comment: Thanks guys, but my problem is not which linter to use, or a linter common to Java and Javascript. My problem is I need to lint just the parts of the documentation files which include sample code.