# tslint-eslint-rules with SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, eslint, tslint, sonarlint, sonarqube5.1

I am quite new with [tslint-eslint-rules](https://github.com/buzinas/tslint-eslint-rules) and I am planning to use this in my project . But moving forward I have to use this as a plugin in SonarQube(which is also quite new to me) as well . I know that Sonar provides TS plugin but is it possible to use tslint-eslint-rules(or any linting) instead of using Sonar provided plugin?

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31980013/how-to-add-jshint-or-eslint-or-tslint-to-sonar-qube) link and it says I can create my own plugin like [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Developing+a+Plugin). I am scratching my head as I am not sure if this is the solution I am looking for.

Can someone please help me out here.

Comment: did you try plugin from answer?

Comment: No I haven't, as I need to get permission for that. So currently focusing on the same.

Comment: if you using sonarqube, use sonarlint

Answer (score 0):

I'm using https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarTS and I can recommend it for 100%. Nice think is you don't have to install sonar, you just add it as plugin to tslint.